# Microsoft Graph API to get all the all the folders from SharePoint Document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph, graph-api

I am trying to get the all the folders from SharePoint library using Graph API.
But I am able to get only level one folder

- Folder 1

  - Folder 1 Sub Folder
- Folder 2

  - Folder  Sub Folder

Using below code able to get Folder 1 and Folder 2 not sub folders names

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites('a22d0d0a-68fb-40b3-9ef7-8001e691a')/lists('8af98cb6-bbf3-4599-b093-7287bcef')/drive/root/children`

Is it possible using graph API to get the all the folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below endpoint to get all folders in the SharePoint Document library:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/ContentType eq 'Folder'
```

And you need to add request header Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly

[image]

Comment: It show below error messages


        "message": "Field 'ContentType' cannot be referenced in filter or orderby as it is not indexed. Provide the 'Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly' header to allow this, but be warned that such queries may fail on large lists.",
        "innerError": {

Comment: As I said, you need to add the request header  Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly